# Function that replaces itself with builtin after first execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to write a function that replaces itself after its first execution?

**first.py:**

```
from second import max
x = max(1,2,3)
y = max(4,5,6)
```

**second.py:**

```
def max(*args):
    ... #rewire references
    return min(args)
```

Can I make it so the second call to `max` calls the builtin, while the first one calls the one from **second.py**? I tried modifying the `globals()` dict, but that had no effect, of course, neither did declaring `global max` in the custom `max` function, even with it renamed (and later named max again).

Is there any way this could be possible? Can I access the importing module in some way?

*(Before someone comes with the inevitable comment: I know this is a bad idea, I don't plan to use it in production, if it's possible. I'm just interested in knowing whether it is doable.)*

**edit:** To clarify, afterwards this should be how it looks like in the REPL:

```
>>> from second import *
>>> max
<function max at 0x10e501400>
>>> x = max(1,2,3)
>>> max
<built-in function max>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, Python is a dynamic language and pretty much everything can be changed at runtime. There are numerous ways to achieve this; a decorator springs to mind.

Comment: You can also `import builtins` and use `builtins.max`

Comment: At the least, you could write an decorator that wraps the function, and checks to see how many times it's been called, choosing between the function and the 'fallback' as needed. I'd have to think longer about how to do this.

Comment: @user3100115 That isn't the question being asked.

Comment: @NathanielFord I'm aware of that. But how could I actually rewire the reference, so that `max` refers directly to the builtin in the first script?

Comment: @L3viathan what do you mean *directly*? It seems like a bit of a waste of time to try to discuss such a vague concept purely for your interest; why not do some experimenting yourself, then you can ask a more concrete question if you hit a more concrete problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If it's a waste of time for you, then don't answer it. I did experiment for about half an hour before coming here. What I mean with *directly* I added, hopefully sufficiently, as an edit.

Comment: ...and what was the result of that experimentation? Half an hour doesn't seem like much, frankly (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761). It's not just a waste of time for *me*, that's the point; I'm all for simple curiosity, but it's a bad fit for the practical Q&A-based format of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file maxtest.py:

```
import __builtin__

_max = __builtin__.max
def max(*args):
    print "Inside non standard max function"
    __builtin__.max = _max
    return min(args)

__builtin__.max = max
```

In file maxtest2.py:

```
import maxtest

x = max(1, 2, 3)
y = max(4, 5, 6)
```

Running python maxtest2.py produces:

```
Inside non standard max function
```

Note the output only happens once, indicated the max function has been changed by the second call.

Comment: Note that `__builtin__` is for python 2; Python 3 should import builtins instead.